# How to compare two files and display contents which are not present in one in a third file

Tags: python, string, loops

I am facing a problem in displaying contents which are not present in two files with respect to one.

**What I am doing is:** There are 10 json files in my folder, i am picking them according to there extension suppose 4 of them have `_api.json` at the end, so i will take them up, the main program which i wrote in `python` validates the json files, then i add the file name of the json files in `names.txt`. Now suppose the next time i run, someone has added 5 more files with `_api.json` and deleted 2 files which were initially present, with `.json` at the end. Now my program runs again and filenames are stored in `names.txt`, and at the beginning of the program, filenames of the previous run are added in a new file `names2.txt` now i want to have a txt file which contains the names of the 2 files which are not present in this run by comparing these two files.

Running the program once, file name get stored in `names.txt`

[image: names]

Running the program again changing the extension, `names.txt` get stores in `names2.txt` and `names.txt` gets updated

[image: names_again]

`names2.txt` contains the previous runs value.

[image: names2]

How to create a file `missing.txt` which compares the above two files and displays: `test1.json`,`test2.json` and `test3.json`

If there is any better way like using `json` or something better please tell.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read files as lists of lines, convert both to `set()` and do `set1 - set2`

```
#lines1 = open('names.txt').read().split('\n')
#lines2 = open('names2.txt').read().split('\n')

lines1 = ['test0.json']
lines2 = ['test0.json', 'test1.json', 'test2.json', 'test3.json']

set1 = set(lines1)
set2 = set(lines2)
set3 = set([""])    # to remove empty lines

missing = set2 - set1 - set3
print('missing:', missing)

text = '\n'.join(missing)
print('text:')
print(text)

with open('missing.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

Result:

```
missing: {'test1.json', 'test2.json', 'test3.json'}
text:
test1.json
test2.json
test3.json
```

Comment: Or read files as *sets* of lines directly.

Comment: How can i not display the empty value

Comment: if last line is empty then you can use `.strip()` before `.split("\n")` to remove it. You can also use `set([""])` and substract for other sets. `missing = set2 - set1 - set([""])`